# Receiving broadcast packet addressed to 255.255.255.255 in C++

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking

I have a device that is discovered by sending a broadcast packet to 255.255.255.255 on port 4930 and the device responds by sending a packet back to 255.255.255.255 on port 4930.

I have a snippet of C++ code which can send a packet to 255.255.255.255 on port 4930 (both source and destination port), but it can't receive a packet back from the broadcast address 255.255.255.255.

I can see the device is working fine, wireshark can see the packets coming back and forth and the propriety software supplied with the device can discover the device just fine, the problem is with the C++ program so please keep on topic with your responses.

Now, as I have said I can send a packet just find, but firstly I can't bind to the IP address 255.255.255.255 to receive the packets. I can change the multicast address to 239.255.255.250 and the socket will bind but I need the address 255.255.255.255.

My snippet of code is below, I am using VC++2010

```
bool CPTUProgramDlg::FindPTU(u_short port, const char * Destaddress){
    {
        //Data to send
        char packet_data[10] = {0x44,0x43,0x55,0x44,0x5f,0x50,0x49,0x4e,0x47,0x00};
        int packet_size=10;

        SOCKET sock;
        struct sockaddr_in addr;

        sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

        // set SO_BROADCAST on a socket to true (1): (so we can transmit to 255 addr)
        //In order to use broadcast the options of socket must change
        char broadcastON = 1;
        setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcastON, sizeof broadcastON);

        if (sock < 0)
            return false;

        addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        addr.sin_port = htons(port);
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(Destaddress); // Specify dest IP

        sendto(sock, packet_data, packet_size, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));

        if (bind(sock,(struct sockaddr*) &addr,sizeof(addr)) != -1){
            char Buff[512];
            recv(sock,Buff,512,0);
        }

        closesocket(sock);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Wireshark screenshot to prove packets are being send:

[image]

Comment: Try binding on 0.0.0.0 and perform filtering by destination ip address. E.g. by using recvfrom instead of recv...

Comment: BTW. this type of packet is broadcast, not multicast. I have seen from your screenshot that the device responds from port 4930 to port 4930 - you may also need to use two different sockets - one for sending and one for receiving.

Comment: Binding on 0.0.0.0 was successful but recvfrom returns -1, my added code is sockaddr * from = new sockaddr[1]; if (recvfrom(sock,Buff,512,0,from,(int*)sizeof(sockaddr))<0){return 0;}

Comment: Ah okay, I just looked at my code and it says Broadcast clearly, not sure how I got broadcast and multicast mixed up :/  thanks for the tip bbonev! I'll try initalising two different sockets and see what happens...

Comment: Excellent Bbonev! That mod worked perfectly!! Thanks Heaps!! The problem was binding to 0.0.0.0 instead of 255.255.255.255 and using separate sockets just as you said!

Comment: @user3063789: You do not need 2 sockets. You can use 1 socket. You can bind() it to 0.0.0.0 on port 4930, enable SOL_BROADCAST, sendto() 255.255.255.255 (better to use a subnet broadcast IP, like 239.255.255.255 if your subnet is 255.255.255.0 for example), then recvfrom() any responses. Your earlier recvfrom() attempt failed because you gave recvfrom() bad parameters, not because you bound the socket wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the wireshark output its seen that the special device is using broadcast to communicate and will use the same port number as source and destination.

Normal socket communication will require using matching port numbers but broadcast messages cannot be exchanged over the same socket, especially when the port numbers do not match as seen with wireshark.

Binding on 255.255.255.255 (`INADDR_BROADCAST`) should generally work but may be limited by your OS privileges and permissions.

You may try to solve the problem by using two sockets - one for receiving and one for sending. Of course the listening socket have to be setup first and bound to 0.0.0.0 (`INADDR_ANY`) and port 4930. In this case there is no easy way to filter by destination address (as I wrongly written in my comment) because most standard socket APIs do not provide a way to get the destination addess from the socket. On Linux there is an exception - `IP_PKTINFO` at `SOL_IP`...

By using recvfrom you will get the source unicast address of the responding device(s). You have to note that if you have more that one such device on your network you will get more than one response.